# Clarification of jest mocking behaviour in nested modules

Tags: jestjs

I'm confused by the jest docs.

This is in the [documentation for `jest.mock()`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/jest-object#jestmockmodulename-factory-options):

> Modules that are mocked with jest.mock are mocked only for the file that calls jest.mock. Another file that imports the module will get the original implementation even if it runs after the test file that mocks the module.

But the [example in the general section on mocking](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mock-functions#mocking-modules) has:

- axios imported in a file called Users
- users.test.js sets up the following mock:

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import Users from './users';

jest.mock('axios');
```

The documentation suggests to me that the test file is should not be able to mock axios in the src `users.js` file... and yet, this is the example in the docs, so surely it should work.

In my test suite I have a test file that implements a very similar pattern

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
const { getApp } = require('../get-app');
jest.mock('node-fetch', () => require('fetch-mock-jest').sandbox())
```

the only differences being that

- `node-fetch`is not imported directly within `get-app.js`, but by one of its dependencies
- I use `require()` rather than `import`

But my example does not work; when I log out the value of teh `fetch` function in the dependency that calls it, I get the unmocked implementation of `node-fetch`.

Can anybody explain

1. How the example in the jest docs is consistent with the description of how mocking is supposed to work
2. Why the example in the docs would work, but mine doesn't

Answer (score 1):

Have discovered the issue is with the project being a monorepo, which means there are multiple copies of node-fetch around.

Other than explicitly requiring the other package's copy of node-fetch (i.e. `require('../other-package/node_modules/node-fetch')`, how could I get the tests of one package to mock a node_module contained in another package's node_modules directory?